# Find if ETag has changed in YoutTube

Tags: php, youtube

I am using the latest version of YouTube API i.e https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3 with PHP client library.
In earlier version, to know if an eTag has changed or updated for a resource, we would use the following code:

```
$client->getIo()->setOptions(array(
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('If-None-Match:<eTag>"')));
try {
   $response = $youtube->playlists->listPlaylists('snippet', array('id' => '6KzzScZSUrs'));
}catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
if (304 == $e->getCode()) {
    $response = new EmptyResponse;
} else {
    $response = null;
}
```

In the new version `getIo()` has been removed. What is the alternative to using this method?